# Serverpod not upgrading from 1.1 to 1.2

Tags: flutter, dart, serverpod

I have followed [this guide](https://docs.serverpod.dev/upgrading/upgrade-to-one-point-two) to upgrade my serverpod project from 1.1.1 to 1.2.1.

I performed `dart pub global activate serverpod_cli` which told me 1.2.1 was available, but it didn't upgrade...

```
...
+ serverpod_cli 1.1.1 (1.2.1 available)
+ serverpod_client 1.1.1 (1.2.1 available)
+ serverpod_serialization 1.1.1 (1.2.1 available)
+ serverpod_service_client 1.1.1 (1.2.1 available)
+ serverpod_shared 1.1.1 (1.2.1 available)
...

Building package executables... ((4((9.5s)
Built serverpod_cli:serverpod_cli.
Installed executable serverpod.
Activated serverpod_cli 1.1.1.
```

I tried `dart pub global deactivate serverpod_cli` and then `dart pub global activate serverpod_cli`, however still the same response.

Any idea how to properly upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

run this :

```
dart pub global activate serverpod_cli 1.2.3
```

then,

```
serverpod version
```

And, if you find a Dart SDK version issue because it requires SDK version >=3.0.0 <4.0.0. then run this and then run above cmd :

```
brew upgrade dart
```